# What is an alternative way to open a modal window instead of window.open?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

My Rails 3.2 application needs to be authorized against each user's account on 3rd party website. I was using `window.open` to do this, but with the different settings that are available in Internet Explorer, it was very hit and miss and causing some user frustration.

I googled `jquery modal window` and basically came up with an embarrassment of riches. Yet I haven't found a way to quite do exactly what I want. Here are my requirements:

- Open a modal child window and give it the focus.
- Prevent the user from returning to the application until the child window is closed.

The closest thing I've found is [Zebra Dialog](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/), but it appears to just have different types of messages that you can show. I need to set the `href` of the window itself so that the user can authenticate and authorize my application for the 3rd party app user account.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use window.open to create a modal window, but it can get pretty messy. You would be better off using a modal plugin for the requirements you have.

I would suggest using Bootstrap, I use this for all my modals.  Easy as to implement and style.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

To open another url in the modal, you could use an iframe in the modal to open up the url you need,  something like this.

http://bootply.com/61676

Comment: Excellent. My site is designed in Bootstrap. I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: This worked perfectly. It is SO much cleaner and better than window.open. Especially if your site is already designed in Bootstrap, this is a superior solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for styling appearance of Modal

```
   <script>

      $("#myModal").animate({"width":"1100px","margin-left":"-100px"},3000,'easeInCirc');

    </script>
```